# How to update a variable in Activity A from Activity B, every time the variable changes?

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

[Image description of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xc9l.png)

I have a music player app. Activity A is my main menu. You choose a song from a list in Activity A and that takes you to the Activity B with intent(passing data like songTitle, songArtist etc).

When I press the back button when I'm in Activity B, it takes me back to Activity A with intent(passing data like songTitle, songArtist etc). I show the currently playing song title and artist name in Activity A at the bottom.

My problem is that if I'm in Activity A and then the song changes AUTOMATICALLY to the next song in ActivityB, the song title and artist name doesn't change in Activity A because I didn't pass any intent from Activity B to A.

I tried to use SharedPreferences in onStart() but the changes in text doesn't apply unless I press the home button on the device and come back again to the Activity A.

How can I listen the variable changes in another activity and update my TextViews accordingly?

Comment: How does Activity B runs after it has been finished by the back press?

Comment: I'm using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT for both activity changes. Also mediaplayer can run in background too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two options here. you can transform those activities to fragments and then you will be able to share data with activity scope view model I believe thats good option and you should do it like that, but if for some reason you have huge codebase and it will be very hard to make those activies fragments you could just add onActivityResult in ActivityA and return current music id or something from ActivityB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Changing Activity B to a fragment will be really hard but not impossible. Can you elaborate about onActivityResult usage? I thought it needs starting the activity with intent. My problem is that I'm waiting in my main menu(Activity A) and a change happens in ActivityB. How can I implement that?

Comment: oooh I didnt read your question quite well sorry about that. when back is clicked and you are back to ActivityA, ActivityB is destroyed and music will be managed with some kind of service am I right?

Comment: I override the onBackButtonPressed in ActivityB and use intent to manually start ActivityA. I also use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, that way media player keeps playing in the background.

Answer (score 0):

> You should look into LiveData

**LiveData** is on observable data class. You can find more about it from here: 
[LiveData Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

Comment: I heard about this before but didn't give it a chance. I will look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem with [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).